# Is the syntax of my Ace oledb connection string correct?

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb, ms-jet-ace

Im just starting to learn programming and i'm trying to create a windows form in c# that would allow me to view excel files through a data grid and be able to manipulate the data by using Oledb's ace connection. So Ive put this connection string in my form load but the thing is it wont populate the data grid ive set up.
Any kind of help would do and let me know if you need more info.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con = new OleDbConnection(@"provider=microsoft.ace.oledb.12.0; data source=<<file path goes here>>;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES";"");
        loaddata();
        showdata();

    }
    void loaddata()
    {
        da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [assets$]", con);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds, "assets");
        ds.Tables[0].Constraints.Add("pk_Userno", ds.Tables[0].Columns[0], true);
        //this can be changed to any other item that you want to use as a primary key.)
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
    void showdata()
    {
        usertxtbx.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[Userno][0].ToString();
        brandtxtbx.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[Userno][1].ToString();
        modeltxtbx.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[Userno][2].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: At first sight your code seems correct, so something different could be the cause. I suggest to put a breakpoint after the Fill and check if the table at index zero contains any row at all. Also, has your grid the property AutoGenerateColumns set to true?

Comment: yes sir, by default it is set to true but ive added "dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;" just to be sure. I'll play around with it some more and keep this post updated. Thank you!